# Can't use BubbleTextView

Tags: java, android

I use the BubbleView library. It seems to me that I registered everything correctly, but the arrow and background of bubbleview do not work out for me. What could be the problem?

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackGround"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_item_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="spark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_item_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_item_username"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:arrowWidth="10dp"
        app:bubbleColor="@color/colorSecondBackGround"
        app:angle="20dp"
        app:arrowHeidth="20dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**gradle**

`implementation 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'`

[And this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CwID.png)

Comment: app:arrowHeidth -> app:arrowHeight :may be that is typo error. and Make sure the color values you used for background color and arrow color are correct and valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_item_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="spark"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_item_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_item_username"
    android:text="Message"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:angle="16dp"
    app:arrowLocation="top"
    app:arrowCenter="true"
    app:arrowPosition="16dp"/>

<com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello BubbleTextVew"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_item_message"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:arrowWidth="8dp"
    app:angle="8dp"
    app:arrowHeight="10dp"
    app:arrowPosition="14dp"
    app:arrowLocation="left"
    app:bubbleColor="#7EC0EE"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/hISsJlX)  I just copied all the code that you sent me but still no result

Comment: In which android version you are testing. Are you changing anything programmatically?(in Java). What is the theme using for the application/activity?

Comment: Oh, it shows well when I run the application on avd but for some reason it doesn’t show on the preview. Can this be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`app:arrowLocation` support `left` `right` `top` `bottom`

`app:arrowCenter` will make arrow `center` in the edge

`app:angle` is the `radius` of bubble view

.........Have you use this...read it may help https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView.

Comment: I added what you wrote, but the result is the same

Comment: I also tried to just copy the code from the github, but still this background does not appear with an arrow

Comment: please send the screenshot of the output.....means AVD screen

Comment: and your type mistake  app:arrowHeight

Answer (score 0):

After starting the application on AVD. The problem is gone. Thank you all very much for the answers!